# DotNetOpenAuth and Hotmail Sign In

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetopenauth

How to retrieve signin email id of Hotmail using DotNetOpenAuth

I have tried this code from sample it gives name and not email id

```
IAuthorizationState authorization = client1.ProcessUserAuthorization(null);
    if (authorization == null)
    {
        // Kick off authorization request
        client1.RequestUserAuthorization(new[] { WindowsLiveClient.Scopes.Basic, "wl.emails" }, new Uri("http://localhost/SignIn.aspx")); // this scope isn't even required just to log in
    }
    else
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(authorization.AccessToken));
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var graph = WindowsLiveGraph.Deserialize(responseStream);
                //this.nameLabel.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(graph.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another item into the `Scope` class

```
/// <summary>
/// Well-known scopes defined by the Windows Live service.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This sample includes just a few scopes.  For a complete list of scopes please refer to:
/// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243646.aspx
/// </remarks>
public static class Scopes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The ability of an app to read and update a user's info at any time. Without this scope, an app can access the user's info only while the user is signed in to Live Connect and is using your app.
    /// </summary>
    public const string OfflineAccess = "wl.offline_access";

    /// <summary>
    /// Single sign-in behavior. With single sign-in, users who are already signed in to Live Connect are also signed in to your website.
    /// </summary>
    public const string SignIn = "wl.signin";

    /// <summary>
    /// Read access to a user's basic profile info. Also enables read access to a user's list of contacts.
    /// </summary>
    public const string Basic = "wl.basic";

    /// <summary>
    /// Read access to a user's personal, preferred, and business email addresses.
    /// </summary>
    public const string Email = "wl.emails";
}
```

Then you can use the following code passing in the correct scope(s) - as you can see from the example you can pass in two or more scopes. You can find the details of the scopes offered [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243646.aspx).

```
var windowsiveClient = WindowsLiveClient.Instance();

var authorization = windowsiveClient.ProcessUserAuthorization();
if (authorization == null)
{
    // Kick off authorization request
    windowsiveClient.RequestUserAuthorization(scope: new[] { WindowsLiveClient.Scopes.Email, WindowsLiveClient.Scopes.Basic });

    // retuning null will force the page to redirect to Windows Live and as we have not specified a callback if authorized will
    // return back to the calling URL - in this instance the 'AttemptSignInForWindowLiveOpenId' controller action.
    return null; // 
}

WindowsLiveGraph windowsLiveModel;

var windowsLiveRequest = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token={0}", Uri.EscapeDataString(authorization.AccessToken)));
using (var response = windowsLiveRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        windowsLiveModel = WindowsLiveGraph.Deserialize(responseStream);
    }
}
```